# SQL query para retornar somente registros preenchidos da tabela

Tags: php, mysqli

Como faço para minha query retornar somente registros que estiverem preenchidos? A minha tabela tem alguns registros em branco que são retornados pela associação.

```
<?php
$consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ws_so_wind, ws_soft_gallery WHERE id_soft = id_img AND id_soft = $id_soft ");
foreach ($consulta as $foto) {
?>
<a href="<?= BASEIMG ?><?= $foto['url_gallery']; ?> " data-lightbox="set" data-title="">
<img itemprop="screenshot" class="screenshot" src="<?= BASEIMG ?><?= $foto['url_gallery']; ?> "></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Eu sugiro que você leia sobre `INNER|LEFT|RIGHT JOIN`, eles vão resolver o seu problema =)

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma explicação muito bacana neste link: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

Acredito que isto resolva seu problema, mas recomendo fortemente estudar as clausulas de junção, vão te ajudar muito na sua jornada :D

```
$consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM ws_so_wind INNER JOIN ws_soft_gallery ON id_soft = id_img WHERE id_soft = $id_soft");
```